# Primary Category no green plus sign

Tags: solspace

In ExpressionEngine 2.8+ with Primary Category 2.3 I am unable to see the Green Plus signs or do anything to add the Primary Category. I attempted with a clean install of EE in a testing environment and was unable to see them there as well. Am I missing a step or is this a bug?

Comment: Anything in your console log?

Comment: Nothing. First place I looked. Looked at all my normal debugging items.

Comment: What about your server logs? Haven't used pc in 2.8 but worked in 273. Email solspace?

Comment: Did you upload the PC themes folder, and perhaps cleared your browser cache for good measure?

Comment: Everything is uploaded. Simply doesn't work. I will email solspace.